# Can a basic variable be the entering variable in Simplex method?

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research, simplex-method

I have got from my teacher that "the entering variable in a maximization problem is the non-basic variable having the most negative coefficient in the Z- row"

I think X1,X2 are non basic and Z,S1,S2... are basic. And I think non of S's can be chosen as entering variable.

But by seeing this

[image]

(http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/larson/elementary_linear/4e/shared/downloads/c09s3.pdf)
I got confused. Please help me to get rid of this confusion.

thanks.

Comment: please add the parts of the pdfthat ae important to this question, questions need to be self containt see the help, how to ask a good question

Comment: Please just read the content of the image above and the question.

Comment: sorry, you have to convince me that you understand the question, and that you don't do see my rant at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19561/88985 , http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask , http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17404/add-give-references-to-how-do-i-ask-good-questions-page , and read Polya "how to solve it" , Understanding the problem

Answer (score 1):

The entering variable can be any of the variables which have negative value in the Z-row. Basic variables have zeros in the Z-row, so they can not enter in that step.